# Nested list comprehension, python, pattern printing

Tags: python

I want to print the below pattern using Nested list comprehension. I am able to achieve this through normal for loops.

```
 1
 2  4
 3  6  9
 4  8 12 16
 5 10 15 20 25
 6 12 18 24 30 36
 7 14 21 28 35 42 49
```

#

```
for i in range (1,8):
    k=0
    for j in range (1,i+1):
        k=k+i
        print k,
    print
```

Output:

```
1
2 4
3 6 9
4 8 12 16
5 10 15 20 25
6 12 18 24 30 36
7 14 21 28 35 42 49
```

Comment: So what is the proplem? You need list comprehension instead of for loops?

Comment: yes, @Ashwani answer is perfect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
pattern = [[j*i for j in range(1,i+1)] for i in range(1,8)]
print ("\n".join(" ".join(map(str, line)) for line in pattern))
```

First line will create a list (2d) containing the pattern and second line is to print the list in proper format.Make  appropriate changes if you are using `python 2`.

Answer (score 3):

List comprehensions aren't a direct replacement for loops in every case.

You use a list comprehension when you want to store the resulting data structure for later use- it takes up space in memory, etc. Since you are only printing out data, list comprehensions don't confer any major advantages, and may actually make your code harder to read and maintain.

Since other people have proposed list comprehension solutions, I'll also be helpful and point out that in python 2, you can get print as a function by putting the following at the start of your file:

`from __future__ import print_function`

Comment: Exactly. Why would OP want to save that entire string in memory when you don't have to

Comment: as @marcin has listed it could be done through generator also. So don't think will take up memory than.

Comment: @garg10may : Memory isn't the only concern- readability is also important. It's good to become familiar with new syntax... but just because you CAN use a list comprehension to do something doesn't mean that you SHOULD. A good rule of thumb: which code would you rather try to bugfix six months from now?

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
print("\n".join(" ".join(str(i*k) for k in range(1, i+1)) for i in range(1,8)))
```

Prints out:

```
1
2 4
3 6 9
4 8 12 16
5 10 15 20 25
6 12 18 24 30 36
7 14 21 28 35 42 49
```

Answer (score 0):

As @abought says, you don't want a nested list comprehension. Print one line at a time and save yourself storing a huge string in memory when you don't have to.

```
>>> for i in range(1, 8):
        print ' '.join(map(str, range(i, i*i+1, i)))


1
2 4
3 6 9
4 8 12 16
5 10 15 20 25
6 12 18 24 30 36
7 14 21 28 35 42 49
```

And here's how another one of @abought's suggestions (the `print_function`) would be implemented:

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> for i in range(1, 8):
        print(*range(i, i*i+1, i), sep=' ')


1
2 4
3 6 9
4 8 12 16
5 10 15 20 25
6 12 18 24 30 36
7 14 21 28 35 42 49
```

Answer (score 0):

in simple manner u can break it like this

```
n = 5 
for i in range(1,n+1):
    nums = 1
    for j in range(0,i):
        print(nums*i,end=" ")
        nums = nums +1 
    print("\r")
```

Comment: I believe the OP specifically wanted list comprehension. Maybe you could explain yourself further as to how this answers the question?